# Comprehend a dictionary that maps the names of months to their numerical values

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary that maps month-names to their particular numerical value (Jan->1, Feb->2, etc), using

```
month_dict = {k:v+1 for v,k in enumerate(['Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'])}
```

instead of returning the correct numerical value `5`, however,

```
print(month_dict['May'])
```

throws a KeyError.

What is wrong?

Comment: `'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'` is a single string

Comment: `print(dict(enumerate('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(","))))` ? or `print({v:i for i,v in enumerate('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(","), 1)})`

Comment: @Rakesh That maps it another way around - index to name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code `enumerate(['Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'])` the list has only one string.

Either use `'` around month names or use `split`

```
month_dict = {k:v+1 for v,k in enumerate(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over one element, that is the entire comma separated string. You need to split the string by commas:

```
>>> month_dict = {k:v+1 for v,k in 
enumerate('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(','))}
>>> print(month_dict['May'])
5
```

Your approach gives the following dictionary:

```
{'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec': 1}
```

So you can see, it's key is `'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'`, there is no individual key, named `May`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains just one string, either use split method or pass the element as separate string in enumerate method

Answer (score 0):

Split by `,` and use `enumerate` with index start `1`

**Ex:**

```
print({v:i for i,v in enumerate('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(","), 1)})
```

**Output:**

```
{'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below,

```
import numpy as np
month_dict = {k:v+1 for v,k in enumerate('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(','))}
month_dict
```

Output

```
{'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}
```